# how to run netbeans application without jre or how to run jre setup if not installed previously

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I made java application's setup file through install4j and it is well known that netbeans application does not run without jre. so my question is that is there any way to install jre automatically if it is not installed previously before installing application.I heard that there is way to create .dll or .bat file for that but i dont know exact about that.So please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks and Regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ikvm.net/

This might be a good route to go, i'm looking into it now. In short it pushes your jar to run on a .net build